# Как реализовать панель навигации, выдвигающаяся при загрузке браузера сверху страницы?

Tags: скрипт, jquery, javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, есть задача: Сделать чтобы сверху браузера при загрузке страницы, автоматом выдвигалась навигация по сайту(список 5 ссылок в строку), причём , нужно чтобы это выдвижение делалось в три шага.

Comment: Отлично. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В начале прописываем через CSS, что бы панель была в самом верхнем положении ,далее после загрузки страницы вызывается функция, которая либо добавляет CSS анимацию ,либо сама выдвигает эту панель.